# Literally 50 SH Zombie processes is system monitor

Tags: zombie

This bothers me now for a while: I have a huge list of Zombie processes whenever my system runs for a while as you can see in my gnome-system monitor. The list is so long that it is hard to find even other processes. Even though the Zombie processes take up almost no resources, this can't be normal. How do I track down the problem / parent process? Using `ps -ax` doesn't provide much info (see below).

[image]
[image]

Thx for help!

Edit:

Looks like Tomboy is the culprit!

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomboy/+bug/956893

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running TomBoy, this can cause a large number of zombie processes.

Close TomBoy and all the zombies will disappear (right-click the Tomboy icon in the lower right notification area if you're using Gnome Shell).

Comment: thx, looks like this is the culprit